# Is Strict-Transport-Security HTTP header name case-sensitive?

Tags: https, http-headers, rfc

I'm digging into the HTTP Strict-Transport-Security specification, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797

It specifies the syntax of the header like this:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000 ; includeSubDomains
```

The RFC specifies that directive names such as "max-age" are case-insensitive, but does explicitly state whether the header name, "Strict-Transport-Security", is case-sensitive. Are there any more general rules to govern that? Or perhaps I'm missing something in the RFC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All HTTP header field names are case-insensitive. [RFC 7230 § 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2) states:

> Each header field consists of a case-insensitive field name followed by a colon (":"), optional leading whitespace, the field value, and optional trailing whitespace.